# Use SQLite.Core to connect to database with Password

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to connet to an SQLite database protecte by password into a project in  .Net Core 2.1

For that, i import:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core(2.2.2)
System.Data.Sqlite.Core(1.0.109.2)

And i want to connect to my database:

```
using (var connexion = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={_Path};Password={_Password};"))
{
    connexion.Open();
}
```

But i have the issue:

> 'SQL logic error Cannot use "Password" connection string property: library was not built with encryption support.

I don't know how to set password differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I remember from my previous experience, The EFCore didn't support encryption out of box and we need to use external libraries.

To use password with SQLite you can read information from [here](https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore)

Comment: Worked for me! Just go to the GitHub repo, scroll down to the instructions and follow those 6 steps. A was pleasantly surprised with how easy it was.